# How do I access a class field from a mixed in method?

Tags: scala, mixins, traits

I'm playing around with mixins and traits in Scala and I've come across a small issue, how do I (without overriding) access a class field from a mixin?

Here's my code:

```
trait Friend {
  def getHelp() = "Gets help"
}

trait Speak {
  def speak(): String
}

class Person(var name: String) extends Speak with Friend {
  override def speak() = s"Hello, I am $name"
}

class Dog(var name: String) extends Speak with Friend {
  override def speak() = "woof woof!"
}

class Cat(var name: String) extends Speak {
  override def speak() = "meow!"
}
```

Nothing too special really, but now I mix `Friend` into an object of `Cat`

```
val felix = new Cat("Felix") with Friend

println(felix.getHelp) // prints "Gets help"
```

How would I write it so that instead of it saying "Gets help" it says "Felix gets help"?
That is, getting the value from the `name` field without having to extend `Friend` at the class definition? (I don't want all instances of `Cat` to also be a `Friend`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the fly:

```
val fred = new Cat("Fred") with Friend {
  override def getHelp() = {
    name + " " + super.getHelp()
  }
}

println(fred.getHelp())
```

or using another trait:

```
trait FriendWithName extends Friend {
  var name: String

  override def getHelp() = {
    name + " " + super.getHelp()
  }
}

val barney = new Cat("Barney") with FriendWithName
println(barney.getHelp())
```

or without `trait Friend` altogether:

```
val wilma = new Cat("Wilma") {
  def getHelp() = {
    name + " gets help"
  }
}
```